# Python pandas - aggregating subportfolios

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have two dataframes, one with a value for each subportfolio, and one with a list of higher level portfolios that each of these subportfolios rolls up to.

```
table1
subportfolio value
top-alpha-1  1
top-alpha-2  2
top-alpha-3  3
top-beta-1   4
top-beta-2   5
top-beta-3   6
top-gamma-1  7
top-gamma-2  8
top-gamma-3  9

table2
portfolio    parent     level
top-alpha-1  top-alpha  1
top-alpha-2  top-alpha  1
top-alpha-3  top-alpha  1
top-beta-1   top-beta   1
top-beta-2   top-beta   1
top-beta-3   top-beta   1
top-gamma-1  top-gamma  1
top-gamma-2  top-gamma  1
top-gamma-3  top-gamma  1
top-alpha    top        2
top-beta     top        2
top-gamma    top        2
top          self       3
```

My goal is to merge these two tables in some way, such that not only the subportfolios get populated with values, but all the higher levels get assigned values based on the aggregation of the portfolios below them.

My first thought was some sort of iteration, but since its a large amount of data this could be very time consuming.

```
table2
portfolio    value parent     level
top-alpha-1  1     top-alpha  1
top-alpha-2  2     top-alpha  1
top-alpha-3  3     top-alpha  1
top-beta-1   4     top-beta   1
top-beta-2   5     top-beta   1
top-beta-3   6     top-beta   1
top-gamma-1  7     top-gamma  1
top-gamma-2  8     top-gamma  1
top-gamma-3  9     top-gamma  1
top-alpha    6     top        2
top-beta     15    top        2
top-gamma    24    top        2
top          45    self       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers all. I've stolen the ideas that you've both given me, and tried to build something that will be as dynamic as possible (any number of levels, any formatting for portfolios, etc.)

```
df = table2.merge(table1, on="portfolio", how="left")
for i in range(2,df.level.max()+1):
    df1 = df.loc[df.level==i-1,:].groupby('parent', 
            as_index=False).sum().rename(columns=
            {"parent":"portfolio"}).set_index('portfolio')
    df = df.set_index('portfolio').combine_first(df1).reset_index()
```

I used the 'setup' provided by piRsquared in his answer. Result:

```
      portfolio  level     parent  value
0           top      3       self   45.0
1     top-alpha      2        top    6.0
2   top-alpha-1      1  top-alpha    1.0
3   top-alpha-2      1  top-alpha    2.0
4   top-alpha-3      1  top-alpha    3.0
5      top-beta      2        top   15.0
6    top-beta-1      1   top-beta    4.0
7    top-beta-2      1   top-beta    5.0
8    top-beta-3      1   top-beta    6.0
9     top-gamma      2        top   24.0
10  top-gamma-1      1  top-gamma    7.0
11  top-gamma-2      1  top-gamma    8.0
12  top-gamma-3      1  top-gamma    9.0
```

If you want to keep the portfolios in order, you can use

```
df = df.sort_values('level')
```

Answer (score 3):

***new answer***

**NOTE: I changed the column name `'subportfolio'` to `'portfolio'`**

```
def agg_lvl(t1, t2):
    lcol = ['level', 'portfolio']
    rcol = ['parent', 'portfolio']
    kwargs = dict(
        left_on='portfolio', right_on='parent',
        suffixes=['_', '']
    )
    lvl = t2[lcol].merge(t2[rcol], **kwargs).drop('portfolio_', 1).merge(t1)
    lvl = lvl.groupby('parent').value.sum().rename_axis('portfolio').reset_index()
    return t1.append(lvl, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(), t2

o1, o2 = agg_lvl(*agg_lvl(table1, table2))

o2.merge(o1)

    level     parent    portfolio  value
0       1  top-alpha  top-alpha-1      1
1       1  top-alpha  top-alpha-2      2
2       1  top-alpha  top-alpha-3      3
3       1   top-beta   top-beta-1      4
4       1   top-beta   top-beta-2      5
5       1   top-beta   top-beta-3      6
6       1  top-gamma  top-gamma-1      7
7       1  top-gamma  top-gamma-2      8
8       1  top-gamma  top-gamma-3      9
9       2        top    top-alpha      6
10      2        top     top-beta     15
11      2        top    top-gamma     24
12      3       self          top     45
```

***setup***

```
table2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'level': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        'parent': [
            'top-alpha',
            'top-alpha',
            'top-alpha',
            'top-beta',
            'top-beta',
            'top-beta',
            'top-gamma',
            'top-gamma',
            'top-gamma',
            'top',
            'top',
            'top',
            'self'],
        'portfolio': [
            'top-alpha-1',
            'top-alpha-2',
            'top-alpha-3',
            'top-beta-1',
            'top-beta-2',
            'top-beta-3',
            'top-gamma-1',
            'top-gamma-2',
            'top-gamma-3',
            'top-alpha',
            'top-beta',
            'top-gamma',
            'top']})

table1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'portfolio': ['top-alpha-1', 'top-alpha-2', 'top-alpha-3', 'top-beta-1', 'top-beta-2', 'top-beta-3', 'top-gamma-1', 'top-gamma-2', 'top-gamma-3'],
        'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    })
```

***old answer***

This solution leverages another solution of mine and may not be exactly what you need... but then again, you didn't make it clear exactly what you needed.  So I took some liberties

First, I a created another dataframe `df` where I split your `subportfolio` column by `'-'`.

```
col = 'subportfolio'
rnm_dict = dict(enumerate(list('321')))
df = table1.drop(col, 1).join(table1[col].str.split('-', expand=True).rename(columns=rnm_dict))
print(df)

   value    3      2  1
0      1  top  alpha  1
1      2  top  alpha  2
2      3  top  alpha  3
3      4  top   beta  1
4      5  top   beta  2
5      6  top   beta  3
6      7  top  gamma  1
7      8  top  gamma  2
8      9  top  gamma  3
```

Now run the aggregation

```
agged = pd.concat([
        df.assign(
            **{x: '' for x in '321'[i:]}
        ).groupby(list('321')).sum() for i in range(1, 4)
    ]).sort_index()


table2.join(agged.set_index(agged.index.to_series().str.join('-').str.strip('-').values), on='portfolio')

    level     parent    portfolio  value
0       1  top-alpha  top-alpha-1      1
1       1  top-alpha  top-alpha-2      2
2       1  top-alpha  top-alpha-3      3
3       1   top-beta   top-beta-1      4
4       1   top-beta   top-beta-2      5
5       1   top-beta   top-beta-3      6
6       1  top-gamma  top-gamma-1      7
7       1  top-gamma  top-gamma-2      8
8       1  top-gamma  top-gamma-3      9
9       2        top    top-alpha      6
10      2        top     top-beta     15
11      2        top    top-gamma     24
12      3       self          top     45
```

Answer (score 2):

```
table3 = table2.merge(table1, 
                      left_on="portfolio", 
                      right_on="subportfolio", 
                      how="left").drop('subportfolio', axis=1)
table3['letter'] = table3.portfolio.str.split('-').str[1]
table3.loc[table3.level==2, 'value'] = table3.groupby('letter').value.sum().values
table3.loc[table3.level==3, 'value'] = table3.loc[table3.level==2, 'value'].sum()
table3.drop('letter', axis=1, inplace=True)

# output
      portfolio     parent  level  value
0   top-alpha-1  top-alpha      1    1.0
1   top-alpha-2  top-alpha      1    2.0
2   top-alpha-3  top-alpha      1    3.0
3    top-beta-1   top-beta      1    4.0
4    top-beta-2   top-beta      1    5.0
5    top-beta-3   top-beta      1    6.0
6   top-gamma-1  top-gamma      1    7.0
7   top-gamma-2  top-gamma      1    8.0
8   top-gamma-3  top-gamma      1    9.0
9     top-alpha        top      2    6.0
10     top-beta        top      2   15.0
11    top-gamma        top      2   24.0
12          top       self      3   45.0
```